# foliations of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, foliations

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional open manifold. We assume that there are two compact sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ of $M$ such that $M\backslash K_1$ is diffeomorphic to $N_1 \times (0,1)$ and $M\backslash K_2$ is diffeomorphic to $N_2 \times (0,1)$, where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are closed manifolds. Can we conclude that $N_1$ is diffeomorphic to $N_2$?